# What type of control does the TCP protocol offer?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-theory

I am asking for a categorization of the control mechanism that TCP uses for flow and congestion control. Obviously, it is closed-loop but would that be discrete? Event-based? Continuous?

Comment: How is this not completely explained in the standard?  Go read RFC 793.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is event based.  You send out some packets and then nothing happens until you either receive an ACK, a NACK, or a certain amount of time passes without receiving anything.  Once one of those events occurs, then you take some actions (e.g. send out more packets or re-send dropped packets, possibly more or less packets than you sent out the first time).